# How to use token [comment:original:url:absolute]

Tags: 8

I want to use the token service for `[comment:original:url:absolute]`.

As far as I understand, it should be something like this

```
$message = $token->replace('Hello the comment is: [comment:original:url:absolute]', ['comment' => $comment_entity]);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work like this.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here since the documentation is vague when it comes to specific examples.

Any pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[comment:original]` only exists when a comment is being updated - without context, it will always be empty. And if you had the context to pass it in this case, you wouldn't need to use the token service in the first place, you could just use what you already had to get the URL.

You probably want to use;

```
[comment:url:absolute]
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, makes sense.